# Botão de Girar 90º uma imagem em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, front-end

Estou criando um editor de imagem e preciso colocar 2 botões que girem 90º pra esquerda ou 90º para direita e que possa girar mais de uma vez

mais só consegui fazer girar uma vez para um lado
gostaria de ajuda para fazer 90º pra esquerda ou 90º para direita e que possa clicar mais de uma vez

```js
let btnLeft = document.getElementById("noventaDireita");
let btnRigth = document.getElementById("noventaEsquerda");
let imgRotate = document.getElementById("imageRotate");

btnLeft.addEventListener('click', () => {
  imgRotate.style.transform = "rotate(90deg)";
})

btnRigth.addEventListener('click', () => {
  imgRotate.style.transform = "rotate(270)";
})
```

Comment: olá Thabata, já deu uma lida na documentação do `transform`? https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/transform

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Acredito que tenha achado a solução lendo a documentação da propriedade transform, mas mesmo assim vou colocar ela aqui pra você:

```js
let btnLeft = document.getElementById("noventaDireita");
let btnRigth = document.getElementById("noventaEsquerda");
let imgRotate = document.getElementById("imageRotate");
let angle = 0;

btnLeft.addEventListener('click', () => {
    angle += 90;
  imgRotate.style.transform = `rotate(${angle}deg)`;
})

btnRigth.addEventListener('click', () => {
    angle -= 90;
  imgRotate.style.transform = `rotate(${angle}deg)`;
})
```

Você só precisaria guardar a angulação atual da imagem em uma variável, e assim que o usuário apertasse o botão, você adicionava ou removia 90 graus dessa variável e enviava pra propriedade transform da imagem, fazendo ela rotacionar.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior